# Server Error in '/' Application when try to browse

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to browse my asp.net project in web browser but continuously getting server error. I have already search a lot over google but didn't find any solution so that's why I am asking you guys.

Error
[image: Server Error in '/' Application.]

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014.I am using this code and database name is "ytube_production".

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="31457280" executionTimeout="36000" targetFramework="4.5" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: You clearly did not search : https://www.google.com/search?q=the+element+buildproviders+cannot+be+defined+below+the+application+level&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=the+element+buildproviders+cannot+be+defined+below+the+application+level

Comment: @Nkosi I searched on google that's why posted this problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have this problem: https://forums.iis.net/t/1160248.aspx?The+element+buildProviders+cannot+be+defined+below+the+application+level

You need to convert the site in IIS to an application.